# How to preserve Typescript return types when calling Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have the following code where i have two functions which return objects of two different types (InterfaceA and InterfaceB)

Now, when i call Promise.all on them, i cant define the type of promises variable so i have to go with any.

```ts
  interface InterfaceA {
    value: string;
  }

  interface InterfaceB {
    value: number;
  }

  const returnA = (): Promise<InterfaceA> => {
    const obj: InterfaceA = {
      value: 'a'
    };
    return Promise.resolve(obj);
  };

  const returnB = (): Promise<InterfaceB> => {
    const obj: InterfaceB = {
      value: 1
    };
    return Promise.resolve(obj);
  };

  const promises: any = [returnA(), returnB()];
  const res = await Promise.all(promises);

  console.log(res)
  const objA: InterfaceA = res[0];
```

The problem is that once i get the response of Promise.all, and try to define the types of the responses, i get the following errors:

```
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'InterfaceA'.
  Property 'value' is missing in type '{}'. (2322)
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'InterfaceA'. (2322)
```

I am not exactly sure how to deal with this and what i can do to preserve the type of the objects that i get in the response of Promise.all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `promises` type isn't precisely inferred as `(Promise<InterfaceA> | Promise<InterfaceB>)[]`.

It can be properly typed with tuple type:

```
  const promises: [Promise<InterfaceA>, Promise<InterfaceB>] = [returnA(), returnB()];
  const res = await Promise.all(promises);
```

This problem can be avoided by eliminating `promises` temporary variable:

```
  const res = await Promise.all([returnA(), returnB()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I didnt fully understand you intention, what i understood is that you wanted to achive something like this with the `as` operator.

```
const returnA = (): Promise<InterfaceA> => {
    const obj: InterfaceA = {
      value: 'a'
    };
    return Promise.resolve(obj as InterfaceA);
  };
```

Comment: no sorry this is not my intention. apologies for not being clear. What i want is that after i call Promise.all and save the results in a variable (res), i would like to save its 0th position value in a variable (objA) with the type "InterfaceA". Does that make sense now?